# Push folders with rsync on a server

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy

I have Ubuntu installed on a VM on my PC.
I need to copy some folder ( recursively ) from Ubuntu to the server.

If I want to download the folders from the server to my VM machine I did this:

```
rsync -av root@aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:/home/my_folder ./
```

my_folder contains other folders and files.
What if I want to upload a folder to the server ?

Hope is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just need to switch the arguments (which represent *source* and *destination*) like

```
rsync -av ./newfolder root@aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:/home/my_folder
```

Have a look at `man rsync` which explains that a trailing slash after `newfolder` would only transfer the *contents* of said directory - in this case, you might want to change the upload destination to `.../my_folder/newfolder`.